# How to use Microsoft Graph API to display manager of a user resource type in Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Question**: Using `Microsoft Graph` how do we display the manager of a user? For example, using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) you can get a signed-in user profile info by calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`. But this call does not return all the fields - specifically not the manager field.

I tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=manager` but it still did not return manager.

In the [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) section of [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) you see a `manager` field for a user's manager. And the [Json representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) of that Relationships shows `manager` field as follows:

```
"manager": { "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.directoryObject" }
```

But I am not sure how do we use it to get he manager of a user.

**UPDATE**:

Following is a screenshot of just a portion of result from the query from the user `@CarlShao`. In fact it is returning tons of attributes for manager object. But I'm showing just current screen of my laptop:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [List manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to expand the user's organizational relationship, you should use the `$expand` parameter, which supports expanding the user's `directReports`, `manager` and `memberOf` relationships.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager
```

reference：[list manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [expand parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter).

---

Update:

You can specify `$select` inside `$expand` to select the individual manager's properties: `$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=displayName)`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=displayName)&$count=true
```

Don't forget to add **request header**: `ConsistencyLevel=eventual`

[image]

Comment: `$expand` parameter is returning tons of attributes. Even some of the attributes are the objects that themselves have some attributes of their own. I'm using `MS Graph SDK` and need only one attribute `displayName` of manager object. How do I achieve this with `$expand` parameter while using [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#examples) to get users with their managers?

Comment: It still returned tons of attributes for manager. Some of these attributes are even objects themselves (such as `onPremisesExtensionAttributes` and `"identities"`). You seem to be on the right track. Is there any way we can filter the result so it displays only `displayName`?

Comment: @nam  Did you add the request header? (This is important!). Can you provide a screenshot of the api that you used https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer to call?

Comment: Yes, I did add the request header and it is showing the same key/value that your screenshot is showing. Also, I have added an UPDATE section to show the screen shot you requested. Screenshot is for the response of  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=displayName)&$count=true`

Comment: @nam  This is strange, can you provide a screenshot of the request api part?

Comment: `Request body` is blank. `Request headers` is exactly the same as your screenshot. And the query is exactly what you gave me - I just copied/pasted from your post. Are you asking for screenshot of something else?

Comment: I've just added upper portion of the Graph Explorer in the UPDATE section, as well - in case that's what you are asking.

Comment: @nam   Are you logged in as a user? https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zg1N.png

Comment: @nam   I reproduced your problem. The reason is that you are not logged in as a user. You only need to log in.

Comment: @nam  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) Thanks!

Comment: @nam   In addition, you need to be aware that sometimes the extension may fail due to caching. You can try to run query it several times. Or use the privacy window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225994/discussion-between-nam-and-carl-zhao).

Comment: Sorry, in my second try today, I had forgotten to add `request header: ConsistencyLevel=eventual`. So you were correct with my own login, it worked. I want to thank you for spending so much time to help me make it work. My upvote for your efforts, as well.